# Cannot import model into my validators.py

Tags: python, django

I am trying to create a custom validation for a model field. My app is named 'Vocabulary' and in there I have a model defined in models.py as below:-

```
from Vocabulary.validators import word_exists


class Vocab(models.Model):
    id  = models.UUIDField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    word = models.CharField(max_length=33, validators=[word_exists])
    meaning = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.id = uuid.uuid4()
        super(Vocab, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.word
```

And inside the validators.py file I have defined custom validator 'word_exists' as follows:-

```
from Vocabulary.models import Vocab
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def word_exists(value):
    if Vocab.objects.filter(word=value).exists():
        raise ValidationError("The word already exists!")
```

In this file [validators.py] I keep getting the error that I cannot import the model Vocab. I have done migrations as well but I am not sure what's causing this error. I  am using Django Version 2.0 . Any help is much appreciated.

The App structure is like this:-

```
Vocabulary[App Name]:-
-> models.py
-> validators.py
```

Comment: Could you tell the file path? and app structuring of the validator and the model?

Comment: You have a circular import - each module is importing the other.  The ideal solution would be to remove the validator and set a unique index on the word column.

Comment: @snakecharmerb can you suggest any other option?

Comment: You could move the validator function into your models.py.

Comment: Or import Vocab within the word_exists function.

Comment: Daniel Roseman thanks for the solution can you please post this as an answer so that i can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following import error is showing up due to circular import

```
ImportError: cannot import name Vocab
```

as you are importing objects from validators.py in your models.py and importing Vocab in validators.py was conflicting with already defined **Vocab** in models.py.

So, one possible solution to this conflict is to import **Vocab** at the place where it is being used, that is, in the local scope of function **word_exists**

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def word_exists(value):
    from Vocabulary.models import Vocab
    if Vocab.objects.filter(word=value).exists():
        raise ValidationError("The word already exists!")
```